# The page is scroll although the drawer is open fixed and temporary

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I add a vuetify drawer to my application, and set the position to `fixed` and `temporary`.

When the drawer is open (and I have overlay), when I try to scroll the drawer stay in position - good. but the problem is the event pass to the page, and the page is do scroll.

How can I fix that?

My code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/veevalidate-components-vuetify-gsker?file=/src/main.js).

- open the link
- click on toggle and the drawer is open.
- try to scroll (with the mouse)
- if you do, it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you give the wrapper div `height:3000px`.
you have to set it to `height:100vh` - in this case it will take the maximum height of your screen (like 100% of it)

Comment: no. I want to set the height to 3000px to simulate a scroll situation.

Comment: So what do you want it to scroll or not? it is not clear...